# $\alpha\in L$ algebraic over $K$ implies $\beta\in L$ algebraic over $K$ iff $\beta$ algebraic over $K(\alpha)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification

The fact that $\beta\in L$ algebraic over $K$ implies $\beta$ is algebraic over $K(\alpha)$ is obvious. Since $\alpha\in L$ is algebraic over $K$, we have $[K(\alpha):K]=n<\infty$. Assume $\beta$ is algebraic over $K(\alpha)$. Then $[K(\beta):K(\alpha)]=d<\infty$. We have
$$
[K(\beta):K]=[K(\beta):K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K]=dn<\infty.
$$

Hence $\beta$ is algebraic over $K$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be true that $K(\beta)$ is an extension of $K(\alpha)$. So using the term $[K(\beta):K(\alpha)]$ is not proper.

You can modify your reasoning as follows:

$$[K(\alpha, \beta):K] = [K(\beta, \alpha):K(\alpha)][K(\alpha):K]$$

which is finite by the assumption that $\beta$ is algebraic over $K(\alpha)$ and $\alpha$ is algerbaic over $K$. So $[K(\alpha, \beta):K]$ is finite and therefore so is $[K(\beta):K]$ and we are done.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that would be an issue, thanks for fixing it for me. Also, can we say $[K(\beta,\alpha):K(\alpha)]$ is at most the degree of the minimal polynomial $m_\beta$ of $\beta$ over $K(\alpha)$? I know that if $\beta\not\in K(\alpha)$, then it *equals* the degree of $m_\beta$, but if $\beta\in K(\alpha)$, then $[K(\beta,\alpha):K(\alpha)]=1$?

Comment: It is always true that if $L:K$ is a field extension and $\beta\in L$, then $[K(\alpha):K]$ is same as the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K$. This remains true even if $\beta\in K$. For then clearly $[K(\beta):K]=1$ and $x-\beta$ is the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K$ which has degree $1$.

Comment: It helps when you upvote too!